# How to use annotations to create OpenAPI (Swagger) documentation on Grails 4

Tags: grails, swagger, openapi

We are creating API documentation for an existing Grails 4 App. We are having difficulties in understanding how to use Swagger annotations.

Let's assume the following Controller:

```
class IntegratorController {

    def maintenanceService

    def saveMaintenance() {
        def message = 'success'
        def status = '200'

        try {
            def maintenanceJson = request.JSON.maintenances
            def ret=maintenanceService.processMaintenanceJSON(maintenanceJson)

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error to process restricions", e)
            message = 'error : ${e.getMessage()}'
            status = '500'
        }

        def result = ['message':message]
        render(status: status, contentType: "application/json", text: result as JSON)
    }

}
```

This controller expects you to send a request JSON like this example:

```
{ "job":42,
  "maintenances": [
    {"idPort":42, "idMaintenance":42, "shipName":"myship01", "obs":"asap"},
    {"idPort":43, "idMaintenance":43, "shipName":"myship02", "obs":"asap"}]}
```

A basic annotation will be this:

```
@Controller("/")
class IntegratorController {

    def maintenanceService

    @Post(uri="/saveMaintenance", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Operation(summary = "Create one or more ship maintenance")
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "If internal service throws an Exception")
    def saveMaintenance() {
        def message = 'success'
        def status = '200'

        try {
            def maintenanceJson = request.JSON.maintenances
            def savedMaintenances=maintenanceService.processMaintenanceJSON(maintenanceJson)

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error to process restricions", e)
            message = 'error : ${e.getMessage()}'
            status = '500'
        }

        def result = ['message':message]
        render(status: status, contentType: "application/json", text: result as JSON)
    }
}
```

Where and how to annotate the request JSON sent in the post operation?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you get this working?  Any problems with dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

The request object is "scoped" by Grails. So you need to use @RequestBody annotation to declare what it is outside the method declaration. You also need to create classes to describe what it is because the JSON deserialization is loosely typed.

This is an example:

```
    @Post(uri="/saveMaintenance", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Operation(summary = "Summary here",
            description = "Description here",
            requestBody = @RequestBody(description = "Inside Operation"), tags = ["IntegratorWebController"])
    @RequestBody(description = "Description here", required = true,
            content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = YourRequestDAO.class, anyOf = [YourRequestDAO.class, YourRequestDAODependency.class])))
    @ApiResponses(value=[
            @ApiResponse(responseCode="200", description = "Return status=OK in success", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = YourResponseDAO.class))),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode="404", description = "Return status=BAD_REQUEST if you mess up", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = YourResponseDAO.class)))])
    def saveOrUpdateActivity(){
(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Well Swagger and OpenAPI are 'schemas' that are preloaded at runtime to build the call structure; GraphQL also has a schema as well to load its call structure.

I did a video on it here to help you understand how this works: https://youtu.be/AJJVnwULbbc

The way Grails did this prior to 4.0 was with plugins like the 'swagger plugin' or with BeAPI plugin (which I maintain).

I don't see a supported plugin in 4.0 so I don't see how they are doing this now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very instructive. Excellent video! Good work!